# Sharing many files at once through google apps

Tags: file-sharing, google-workspace

We are using Google Apps for Business (paid plan) and need to share many (hundreds to thousands) files at once to all users in the organization and have them show up in either "My Drive" (preferably) or "Shared With Me" or some other way that has them sync with the desktop app automatically.

We've tried setting the default document visibility to "This Organization" which makes the documents available to any user, but they must search for it and the documents don't appear in their drive, or shared view.

Is there a simple way to do this with all files by default?